# Amazon SDK mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create an app the allows users to upload photos or any sort of file type to the app and then display them on the front end. I am using Amazon sdk on node.js to handle to upload to an S3 bucket and I can get it to upload and display the image in the app while the server is running, but when I restart it, I lose the image. The uploaded file persists in my s3 bucket but I cannot seem to get the S3 link to submit to my mongodb database I have set up to display after I restart the server. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The link is usually

```
http://<your bucket name>.s3.<the s3 region>.amazonaws.com/<filename>
```

For private buckets, you can get a signed url with the [getSignedUrl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) method